# A javaFX Stage could be both StageStyle.UTILITY and StageStyle.TRANSPARENT?

Tags: javafx, stage

I mean that when using a stage with stageStyle.UTILITY, I don't want to show the "solid white background " but a transparent background.

I need a stage doesn't shown on the windows' task bar below(stageStyle.UTILITY can satisfy), and I need a transparent background（StageStyle.TRANSPARENT can satisfy）so that I can define the close button style of my stage.

But it seems strange that stageStyle.UTILITY or StageStyle.TRANSPARENT only fit one of my request.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a transparent utility stage in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859152/5932611  this answer has a very nice way to do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already OK!
Also invoke dialogStage.initOwner(parentStage)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner%28javafx.stage.Window%29

Comment: I see when the parentStage is minimized or maximized, the childStage will be minimized and maximized too. Could you please share the way to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

something thus?

[image]

has an effect on the background

leads code

```
dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet possible in javafx but javafx is swing compatible so you can use swing to make a swing equivalent to a transparent utility stage. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx/27763555#27763555) for some examples. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
Group rootGroup = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup, 339, 319, Color.TRANSPARENT);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.centerOnScreen();
stage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, Jackson, But you may mistake. StageStyle.TRANSPARENT can't make my popup stage not shown on the windows' task bar below, Only stageStyle.UTILITY can satisfy.  So i need a popup stage with both stageStyle.UTILITY and transparent background(no default close button).

Comment: Already OK.  
Also invoke dialogStage.initOwner(parentStage)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner%28javafx.stage.Window%29

Answer (score 0):

Look here 
[How can I remove my javafx program from the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712293/how-can-i-remove-my-javafx-program-from-the-taskbar)

just add (to move it out of sight)

```
primaryStage.setX(Double.MAX_VALUE);
primaryStage.setY(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

and replace

```
mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

with

```
mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```