# Is it possible to have a JavaFX Stage that is both hidden from the taskbar and lacking a border?

Tags: java, javafx, window, border, taskbar

I know that `Stage.InitStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)` will create a stage that, as long as it has been init to an owner, will not be present in the task bar (or system specific equivalent).

I also know that `Stage.InitStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)` will create a stage with no border or buttons for closing/minimizing/maximizing.

Is it possible to have both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A javaFX Stage could be both StageStyle.UTILITY and StageStyle.TRANSPARENT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502451/a-javafx-stage-could-be-both-stagestyle-utility-and-stagestyle-transparent)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712293/how-can-i-remove-my-javafx-program-from-the-taskbar

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet possible in javafx but javafx is swing compatible so you can use swing to make a swing equivalent to a transparent utility stage. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx/27763555#27763555) for some examples. I hope that this helps.