# JavaFx: StageStyle.UTILITY without close button

Tags: java, javafx

I need to use  StageStyle utility because I need to hide window icon in taskbar. However, I also need to hide and close button. How to do it? Or maybe there is another solution - no window title bar + no icon in task bar?

Comment: "need to hide and close button" is unclear.  Also do you want a title bar?  Maybe draw what you want.

Comment: @brian Yes, I want ot hide and title bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is more of a general one:* The core problem is that JavaFX doesn't allow you to hide the taskbar icon. So I guess you really don't want to use a Utility StageStyle, but rather are forced to.

Swing allows you to hide the taskbar icon. So the hackaround is simple: Use JavaFX inside a Swing JFrame and hide it from the taskbar.

You can take a look at the widget code in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx/27763555#27763555) here as an example.