# JavaFX Combining Utility and transparent stage style

Tags: java, swing, javafx, transparent, taskbar

I would like to have a JavaFX Application that doesn't appear in the taskbar and also does not have window decoration, how can i achieve that, any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried this:

[Is it possible to have a transparent utility stage in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx?rq=1)

It is working fine, but the graphics are pretty bad, so this is not a good way in my opinion.The bad graphics are caused byby the not working antialiasing inside of the JFXPanel.The JFXPanel seems to be bugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that with JavaFX, but i found a workaround using Swing.Just create a JFrame and set its Type to `Type.UTILITY` and set Undercorated to `true`. Then create an JFXPanel embedding the FX Scene.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setType( Type.UTILITY );
frame.setUndecorated( true );
final JFXPanel mainJFXPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add( mainJFXPanel );

mainJFXPanel.setScene( getScene() ); //The "getScene()" is just a placeholder
```

Comment: Well, uh, i know that answer is already 2 years old, but yeah, you probably don't want to do this, since it will most likely cause rendering / antialiasing issues.