# How can I remove my javafx program from the taskbar

Tags: javafx, stage

I need remove my javafx app from the taskbar. I tried `StageStyle.UTILITY`. This is works but I need both UNDECORATED and UTILITY stage styles or another solvings.
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: This seems a bit similar to [Is it possible to have a transparent utility stage in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759019/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-utility-stage-in-javafx/27763555#27763555), though none of the answers to those questions seemed to do what this question is asking for (at least in OS X, a JavaFX icon always showed in the OS X dock for me and I would not know how to stop that occurring).

Answer (score 9):

Sorry you've been waiting so long for some sort of an answer on this, the following is mainly for people who come to this in the future hoping to discover a way of achieving this.

Let me start of by saying I wouldn't consider the following a solution but more of a workaround.
Assigning more than one `initStyle` to a stage is not possible however hiding the application from the task-bar and assigning an `initStyle` other than utility to the stage that is shown is.

To achieve this one must create two stages, the stage they want the user to see, and an another stage that will be considered the parent of the main stage and will be of `initStyle.UTILITY` this will prevent the icon from showing in the task-bar.

Below you can see the hello world example from oracles documentation modified to allow for an undecorated window with no icon (Note if one wanted to achieve a transparent/decorated window they could do so by changing the style of `mainStage`).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class MultipleStageStyles extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        primaryStage.setOpacity(0);
        primaryStage.setHeight(0);
        primaryStage.setWidth(0);
        primaryStage.show();
        Stage mainStage = new Stage();
        mainStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        mainStage.show();
    }
}
```